# Lisp: Setting element in one row results in setting that element in every row (list of lists)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am setting the element at row 1, column 1 of a 2D Matrix represented as a list of lists result in setting all elements at column 1 of the 2D Matrix? It is required that I rerpresent the 2D matrix as a list of lists. Below is my code:

```
(defvar matrix (make-list 5 :initial-element (make-list 5)))
(print (format nil "matrix (before) = ~a" matrix))
(setf (nth 1 (nth 1 matrix)) 1)
(print (format nil "matrix (after) = ~a" matrix))
```

With the following output:

> "matrix (before) =  ((NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL
> NIL NIL NIL NIL)  (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL))"

> "matrix (after) =  ((NIL 1 NIL NIL NIL) (NIL 1 NIL NIL NIL) (NIL 1 NIL
> NIL NIL)  (NIL 1 NIL NIL NIL) (NIL 1 NIL NIL NIL))"

This seems strange, considering that I only set an element in the 2D matrix once.

Answer (score 2):

"Setting a value in one object is causing it to appear in other objects" is a problem that occurs when you have perpetrated **destructive manipulation** in your Lisp program, also known as **mutation**.

When you mutate objects, you must take great care to ensure that the objects you are not mutating are not **shared** in ways that will cause surprises.

Many of the cons cell and list manipulating functions in Lisp are optimized toward maximal **substructure sharing**.

You can see this with a simple example:

```
(let* ((list-one (list 2 3 4))
       (list-two (cons 1 list-one)))
  (list list-one list-two))
```

This yields `((2 3 4) (1 2 3 4))`. `list-1` is `(2 3 4)` and `list-2` is `(1 2 3 4)`.  However, the `cons` function has allocated only one new cons cell. The `(2 3 4)` part of `list-two` is shared structure, coinciding with the `list-one` object. Thus if we change the code like this:

```
(let* ((list-one (list 2 3 4))
       (list-two (cons 1 list-one)))
  (setf (nth 1 list-one) 30)
  (list list-one list-two))
```

The output is:

```
((2 30 4) (1 2 30 4))
```

Look, we assigned `30` into the second place of `list-one`. But this `30` has also showed up in the third place of `list-two`.

The solution is: debug your code not to do that. In the above example, we can do this:

```
(let* ((list-one (list 2 3 4))
       (list-two (cons 1 (copy-list list-one))))
  (setf (second list-one) 30)
  (list list-one list-two))

--> ((2 30 4) (1 2 3 4))
```

We inserted a call to `copy-list` to make a fresh copy of `list-one`. This object is then passed to `cons`, and only to `cons`. So then we know that `list-two` is brand new structure, not shared with anything else in the image. When we assign to the second position of `list-one`, `list-two` is unaffected.

**How has substructure sharing occurred in your program?** Let's see:

```
 (make-list 5 :initial-element (make-list 5)))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The underlined expression is evaluated once, to produce an object which is passed into the `make-list` function. The `make-list` function repeats that object into the five positions of a new list. There is only one object; any change you make to one appears in the others, because there are in fact no others.

We can avoid the substructure sharing by evaluating `(make-list 5)` five times to create five lists, and collecting them into a list:

```
(loop repeat 5 collect (make-list 5))
```

So that is the main strategy in dealing with mutation: to copy constituent objects in order to avoid substructure sharing.

Another strategy is to keep mutation local to a scope: mutate only those objects which did not come from anywhere else, but were just newly created in that piece of code. Then, once those objects are released for other code to use, do not mutate them. For instance, it's a common Lisp idiom to `push` items onto a local list (which builds up the result in reverse order), and then call `nreverse` to  destructively reverse the list before returning it. The list is not shared with anything, so usually that code can easily be seen to be correct by inspection.

There is no fixed recipe; in each situation where mutation provides a convenient solution, you have to think about how to best use it, while preventing unwanted effects. Any time you mutate an object, you have to worry about whether that object exists elsewhere.  Which of those elsewheres must see the mutation, which must not see the mutation.

Graphically, your object looks like this:

```
matrix ──┐
         │
         ▼
      ┌─────┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐     ┌─────┬─────┐
      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
      │  @  │  @──┼─────►│  @  │  @──┼─────►│  @  │   @─┼─────►│  @  │  @──┼────►│  @  │ NIL │
      │  │  │     │      │  │  │     │      │  │  │     │      │  │  │     │     │  │  │     │
      └──┼──┴─────┘      └──┼──┴─────┘      └──┼──┴─────┘      └──┼──┴─────┘     └──┼──┴─────┘
         │                  │                  │                  │                 │
         │                  │                  │                  │                 │
         │                  │                  │                  │                 │
         │                  │                  │                  │                 │
         │                  │                  │                  │                 │
         │                  ▼                  ▼                  ▼                 │
         │◄─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
         │
         │
      ┌──▼──┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐      ┌─────┬─────┐     ┌─────┬─────┐
      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
      │ NIL │  @──┼─────►│ NIL │  @──┼─────►│ NIL │  @──┼─────►│ NIL │  @──┼────►│ NIL │ NIL │
      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
      └─────┴─────┘      └─────┴─────┘      └─────┴─────┘      └─────┴─────┘     └─────┴─────┘
```

`matrix` is a list of five elements, which are all pointers to the same list of five `NIL`s.

Answer (score 0):

It is a somewhat subtle bug. When you call `(make-list 5 :initial-element (make-list 5)`, the inner `(make-list 5)` is evaluated before being passed to the outer `make-list`. As a result, each row of your matrix points to the same list in memory. Therefore all rows of your matrix reference the same location in memory.

To resolve the issue, I recommend `(loop repeat 5 collect (make-list 5))` instead.

Comment: One could also deduct it from the fact that `make-list` is a function and that it would evaluate all its arguments and not for each element it creates.